# Clojure parse nested vectors

Tags: clojure, tree, zipper

I am looking to transform a clojure tree structure into a map with its dependencies

For example, an input like:

```
[{:value "A"} 
  [{:value "B"} 
    [{:value "C"} {:value "D"}] 
  [{:value "E"} [{:value "F"}]]]]
```

equivalent to:

```
:A
  :B
    :C
    :D
  :E
    :F
```

output:

```
 {:A [:B :E] :B [:C :D] :C [] :D [] :E [:F] :F}
```

I have taken a look at tree-seq and zippers but can't figure it out!

Comment: I think there may be a misplaced bracket in your first input example, that structure doesn’t quite match the other two examples. Also the output map is missing a value for `:F`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to build up the desired map while using a zipper to traverse the tree. First let's simplify the input tree to match your output format (maps of `:value` strings → keywords):

```
(def tree
  [{:value "A"}
   [{:value "B"} [{:value "C"} {:value "D"}]
    {:value "E"} [{:value "F"}]]])

(def simpler-tree
  (clojure.walk/postwalk
   #(if (map? %) (keyword (:value %)) %)
   tree))
;; [:A [:B [:C :D] :E [:F]]]
```

Then you can traverse the tree with `loop`/`recur` and `clojure.zip/next`, using two `loop` bindings: the current position in tree, and the map being built.

```
(loop [loc (z/vector-zip simpler-tree)
       deps {}]
  (if (z/end? loc)
    deps ;; return map when end is reached
    (recur
     (z/next loc) ;; advance through tree
     (if (z/branch? loc)
       ;; for (non-root) branches, add top-level key with direct descendants
       (if-let [parent (some-> (z/prev loc) z/node)]
         (assoc deps parent (filterv keyword? (z/children loc)))
         deps)
       ;; otherwise add top-level key with no direct descendants
       (assoc deps (z/node loc) [])))))
=> {:A [:B :E], :B [:C :D], :C [], :D [], :E [:F], :F []}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but you've actually changed the structure of the example input, by removing the `[` before the E node. I think you're probably right and OP mis-typed the input, because the proposed input format is really super-bizarre and what you've interpreted it as is reasonable, but it bears pointing out.

Comment: @amalloy thanks for pointing out, I meant to call this out and forgot. I inferred the “correct” tree from the question’s “equivalent to” and “output” samples when I noticed the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do using the tupelo.forest library.  I reformatted your source data to make it fit into the Hiccup syntax:

```
(dotest
  (let [relationhip-data-hiccup [:A
                                 [:B
                                  [:C]
                                  [:D]]
                                 [:E
                                  [:F]]]
        expected-result         {:A [:B :E]
                                 :B [:C :D]
                                 :C []
                                 :D []
                                 :E [:F]
                                 :F []} ]
    (with-debug-hid
      (with-forest (new-forest)
        (let [root-hid (tf/add-tree-hiccup relationhip-data-hiccup)
              result   (apply glue (sorted-map)
                         (forv [hid (all-hids)]
                           (let [parent-tag (grab :tag (hid->node hid))
                                 kid-tags   (forv [kid-hid (hid->kids hid)]
                                              (let [kid-tag (grab :tag (hid->node kid-hid))]
                                                kid-tag))]
                             {parent-tag kid-tags})))]
          (is= (format-paths (find-paths root-hid [:A]))
            [[{:tag :A}
              [{:tag :B} [{:tag :C}] [{:tag :D}]]
              [{:tag :E} [{:tag :F}]]]])
          (is= result  expected-result ))))))
```

API docs [are here](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.forest.html).  The project README (in progress) [is here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc).  A video from the 2017 Clojure Conj [is here](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM).

You can see the above live code [in the project repo](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.cljc#L1402).